# Isomorphism between modules and submodules

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Let $A$ be a ring, $M_1,\ldots,M_n$ be A-modules and $N_j$ be an $A$-submodule of $M_j$ for $1 \leq j \leq n$

Prove that 
$$(M_1 \times M_2 \times \cdots \times M_n)/(N_1 \times N_2 \times \cdots \times N_n) \cong (M_1/N_1) \times (M_2/N_2)\times\cdots\times (M_n/N_n)$$

I'm completely lost with this. All I can think of being relevant is the First Isomorphism Theorem and the definition of a submodule.

Would it have something to do with dividing basis elements?

Comment: The first isomorphism theorem could help, yes. For each $i$ you have the quotient map $M_i \to M_i/N_i$. You can take the product of these to get a map $\prod M_i \to \prod (M_i/N_i)$ (how easy this is to see depends on how you've developed the theory) and then argue that it's surjective and find the kernel. There is really no great notion of a basis element with the given setup.

Comment: But how would ∏Mi relate to ∏Mi/∏Ni?

Comment: The latter is a quotient of the former.

Comment: Wait so here you define the map to be such that ker(f)=∏Ni?